# Firebase: Stop refresh of data after going of page

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I currently have a Nav bar that switches between different `Containers` that are stored in a list. One of the `Containers` contains a `StreamBuilder` to setup a listener from firebase. However, my problem is that every time I navigate from the page and back to it, the page "refreshes" and pulls data again from firebase. I would like it not to do this, as that will lead to an increase in my reads, incurring costs.

My current code is this:

```dart
StreamBuilder(
            stream:
                Firestore.instance.collection('Lessons').limit(4).snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData)
                return const Text('Loading your Lessons....');
              print("rebuilt");
              return ListView.builder(
                itemExtent: 80.0,
                itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                    _buildListItem(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]),
              );
            }),
```

Is there any way to keep the previously loaded `lessons` to display next time the page is come back to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because you are using

```
stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Lessons').limit(4).snapshots(),
```

in your `build()` method, which can get called many-many times.

So a better way would be to declare a variable like:

```
Stream stream;
```

And in your `initState` define it like:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  stream = Firestore.instance.collection('Lessons').limit(4).snapshots();
}
```

And after this you can use it like:

```
stream: steam
```

Since `initState` is just called once in the tree (unless you are doing some other special stuff), so you only make a read request just once, and after that you use it anywhere you want.

Comment: I have followed this way of loading Firestore data, but am finding that when I initially go to my first page that draws Firestore data, it doesn't load initially. I have to navigate away from that page, go back, and then it loads. Any thoughts?

Comment: Bit late but if anyone else comes across this I believe you need to use the ‘late’ before the variable. That’s what solves it for me.